# Why would this preg_match_all suddenly stop working?

Tags: php, file-get-contents

This code was working for days until it stopped working at the worst possible time. It simply pulls weather alert information from a NOAA website and displays it on my page. Can someone please tell me why this would suddenly fail?

```
$file = file_get_contents("http://forecast.weather.gov/showsigwx.php?warnzone=ARZ018&warncounty=ARC055");  
preg_match_all('#<div id="content">([^`]*?)<\/div>#', $file, $matches); 
$content = $matches[1];  

echo "content = ".$content."</br>" ;
echo "matches = ".$matches."</br>" ;
print_r ($matches); echo "</br>";
echo "file </br>".$file."</br></br>" ;
```

Now all I get is an empty array.

This is the output..

```
content = Array
matches = Array
Array ( [0] => Array ( ) [1] => Array ( ) )
file = the full page as requested by file_get_contents
```

Answer (score 7):

Your regexp is trying to match the literal string `<div id="content">`, followed by some (as few as possible) chars *that are not backticks* (`` ` ``), followed by the literal string `</div>`.

However, in the current set of [NOAA warnings and advisories](http://forecast.weather.gov/showsigwx.php?warnzone=ARZ018&warncounty=ARC055), there *is* a backtick between `<div id="content">` and `</div>`:

```
A SLIGHT RISK FOR SEVERE THUNDERSTORMS IS IN EFFECT FOR NORTHEAST
MISSISSIPPI SOUTH OF A CALHOUN CITY TO FULTON MISSISSIPPI LINE
FROM LATE THIS AFTERNOON THROUGH THIS EVENING. DAMAGING WINDS
WILL BE THE MAIN THREAT...HOWEVER AN ISOLATED TORNADO CAN`T BE
RULED OUT.
```

That's why your regexp doesn't match.

The simplest "fix" would be to replace the regexp with, say:

```
'#<div id="content">(.*?)<\/div>#s'
```

where `.` will, with the `s` [modifier](http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php), match *any* character.

However, what you really should do is [use a proper HTML parser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/how-to-parse-and-process-html-xml-with-php) to extract the text, instead of trying to parse HTML with regexps.

---

**Edit:** Here's a quick example (untested!) of how you could do this with DOMDocument:

```
$html = file_get_contents( $url );  
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML( $html );
$content = $doc->getElementById( 'content' )->textContent;
```

or even just:

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTMLFile( $url );
$content = $doc->getElementById( 'content' )->textContent;
```

Comment: WOW. Thank You. I never would have caught that.  I am really new to php and am trying to learn as I go. What you you recommend that I use?

Comment: [DOMDocument::loadHTML()](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.loadhtml.php) works pretty well and is built into PHP.

Comment: I really appreciate the input and I have been trying to get my head around this, unsuccessfully, for the past hour. I usually prefer to learn what I am doing but i really need to get this back up quickly. how would I implement the DOM method?

Comment: Only one error...Warning: DOMDocument::loadHTMLFile() [domdocument.loadhtmlfile]: htmlParseEntityRef: no name in http://forecast.weather.gov/showsigwx.php?warnzone=ARZ018&warncounty=ARC055, line: 87 in C:\xampp\htdocs\greenecountyskywarn.org\alert.php on line 3

Comment: @user1928523: No problem, glad to see it's working. Don't forget to click the check mark on the left to accept this answer! :)